# Stored procedures with Entity Framework, DataAcessLayer vs ModelController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado

I'm currently building an ASP.NET application using Entity Framework and stored procedures. My original idea was building the application with a data access layer where I call my stored procedures.

However when I created the controller I choose the "ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller with Views using Entity Framework" which creates a controller using the data model created from my database by EF.

Something like this:

```
private Entities db = new Entities(); //Datamodel

// GET: Employees1
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Employees.ToList());
}
```

And I can also create the controller calling my data access layer instead:

```
DataAccesLayer dal = new DataAccesLayer();

// GET: Employee
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(dal.GetAllEmployees());
}
```

Calling the data access layer is a couple of hundred milliseconds slower, however I think it's quite nice having a separate class calling my stored procedures.

So my question to you is: which is the best approach? What would you have done?

Comment: So - what exactly do you think you get from using `DataAccessLayer` versus just using the EF `Entities` ? What **benefit** do you see in having such a separate class?

Comment: An EF model including a `DbContext` and entity classes *is* a data access layer.

Comment: Yeah I think is just got caught in the moment. I can use the DBContext class and call my store procedures from there. Thanks for input!